# split line into multiple via splitting specific field

Tags: bash, sed, awk, split

I have multiple lines like:

```
"390";"902";"from 4670000 to 4679999, from 4680000 to 4689999, from 9960000 to 9969999";"something1";"something2";"20.09.04"
"390";"903";"from 0770000 to 0779999, from 9170000 to 9179999";"something3";"something4";"09.09.04"
```

What I need is:

```
"390";"902";"from 4670000 to 4679999";"something1";"something2";"20.09.04"
"390";"902";"from 4680000 to 4689999";"something1";"something2";"20.09.04"
"390";"902";"from 9960000 to 9969999";"something1";"something2";"20.09.04"
"390";"903";"from 0770000 to 0779999";"something3";"something4";"09.09.04"
"390";"903";"from 9170000 to 9179999";"something3";"something4";"09.09.04"
```

As you can see I need to split variable3 on from/to tag (NOTE there is a space sometimes between ",").

Ideally, I need resulting output:

```
"390";"902";"4670000";"4679999";"something1";"something2";"20.09.04"
"390";"902";"4680000";"4689999";"something1";"something2";"20.09.04"
"390";"902";"9960000";"9969999";"something1";"something2";"20.09.04"
"390";"903";"0770000";"0779999";"something3";"something4";"09.09.04"
"390";"903";"9170000";"9179999";"something3";"something4";"09.09.04"
```

I've already found out I can split via awk, but I'm not sure how to copy rest of the line:

```
awk -F\, '{                       
  for (i = 0; ++i <= NF;)
    print i, $i
  }' <<<'from 4670000 to 4679999, from 4680000 to 4689999, from 9960000 to 9969999'
1 from 4670000 to 4679999
2  from 4680000 to 4689999
3  from 9960000 to 9969999
```

Sorry, this is my first question here, feel free to point me how should I correct it in order to get it fully answered.

Thanks!

Comment: +1 for sample input, required output and (gasp), an attempt to solve your problem. Keep posting!

Comment: sorry, I'll add more examples next time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an input of:

```
"390";"902";"from 4670000 to 4679999, from 4680000 to 4689999, from 9960000 to 9969999";"something1";"something2";"20.09.04"
"390";"903";"from 0770000 to 0779999, from 9170000 to 9179999";"something3";"something4";"09.09.04"
```

This code

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    FS = ";"
}

{
    t = $3
    gsub(/"/, "", t)
    n = split(t, a, /, /)
    for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        print $1 ";" $2 ";\"" a[i] "\";" $4 ";" $5 ";" $6
    }
}
```

Would give

```
"390";"902";"from 4670000 to 4679999";"something1";"something2";"20.09.04"
"390";"902";"from 4680000 to 4689999";"something1";"something2";"20.09.04"
"390";"902";"from 9960000 to 9969999";"something1";"something2";"20.09.04"
"390";"903";"from 0770000 to 0779999";"something3";"something4";"09.09.04"
"390";"903";"from 9170000 to 9179999";"something3";"something4";"09.09.04"
```

Condensed form (I don't think it could really be called as a true "one-liner"):

```
awk -F ";" -- '{ t = $3; gsub(/"/, "", t); n = split(t, a, /, /); for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i) print $1 ";" $2 ";\"" a[i] "\";" $4 ";" $5 ";" $6 }'
```

And this code

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    FS = ";"
}

{
    t = $3
    gsub(/"|from /, "", t)
    n = split(t, a, /, | to /)
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i += 2) {
        print $1 ";" $2 ";\"" a[i] "\";\"" a[i + 1] "\";"$4 ";" $5 ";" $6
    }
}
```

Would give

```
"390";"902";"4670000";"4679999";"something1";"something2";"20.09.04"
"390";"902";"4680000";"4689999";"something1";"something2";"20.09.04"
"390";"902";"9960000";"9969999";"something1";"something2";"20.09.04"
"390";"903";"0770000";"0779999";"something3";"something4";"09.09.04"
"390";"903";"9170000";"9179999";"something3";"something4";"09.09.04"
```

Condensed form:

```
awk -F ";" -- '{ t = $3; gsub(/"|from /, "", t); n = split(t, a, /, | to /); for (i = 1; i <= n; i += 2) print $1 ";" $2 ";\"" a[i] "\";\"" a[i + 1] "\";"$4 ";" $5 ";" $6; }'
```

Script is tested with gawk, nawk and mawk.

Comment: doesn't work for that input: ``"390";"903";"from 0770000 to 0779999,from 9170000 to 9179999";"*";"something4";"09.09.04"``

Comment: @Aleks-DanielJakimenko I don't see that as part of the example.

Comment: He said ``As you can see I need to split variable3 on from/to tag (NOTE there is a space sometimes between ",").`` which I understand like "sometimes there are spaces around ',' and sometimes there are no spaces"

Comment: Assuming it's only sometimes and not always then you're correct. However it could it be easily solved by replacing any `, ` expression to `, ?`.

Answer (score 3):

awk one-liner:

```
awk -F'";"' -v OFS='";"' '{n=split($3,a,/,\s*/);for(i=1;i<=n;i++){$3=a[i];print}}' file
```

outputs:

```
kent$  cat f
"390";"902";"from 4670000 to 4679999, from 4680000 to 4689999, from 9960000 to 9969999";"something1";"something2";"20.09.04"
"390";"903";"from 0770000 to 0779999, from 9170000 to 9179999";"something3";"something4";"09.09.04"

kent$  awk -F'";"' -v OFS='";"' '{n=split($3,a,/,\s*/);for(i=1;i<=n;i++){$3=a[i];print}}' f
"390";"902";"from 4670000 to 4679999";"something1";"something2";"20.09.04"
"390";"902";"from 4680000 to 4689999";"something1";"something2";"20.09.04"
"390";"902";"from 9960000 to 9969999";"something1";"something2";"20.09.04"
"390";"903";"from 0770000 to 0779999";"something3";"something4";"09.09.04"
"390";"903";"from 9170000 to 9179999";"something3";"something4";"09.09.04"
```

**EDIT**

if you want the `from...to` to be parsed too, still an awk oneliner:

```
awk -F'";"' -v OFS='";"' '{n=split($3,a,/,\s*/);for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
{$3=a[i];sub(/\s*to\s*/,"\";\"",$3);sub(/\s*from\s*/,"",$3);print}}' file
```

test with same input file:

```
kent$  awk -F'";"' -v OFS='";"' '{n=split($3,a,/,\s*/);for(i=1;i<=n;i++){$3=a[i];sub(/\s*to\s*/,"\";\"",$3);sub(/\s*from\s*/,"",$3);print}}' f                              
"390";"902";"4670000";"4679999";"something1";"something2";"20.09.04"
"390";"902";"4680000";"4689999";"something1";"something2";"20.09.04"
"390";"902";"9960000";"9969999";"something1";"something2";"20.09.04"
"390";"903";"0770000";"0779999";"something3";"something4";"09.09.04"
"390";"903";"9170000";"9179999";"something3";"something4";"09.09.04"
```

Comment: Note that he wants "from .. to .." field to be parsed as well.

Comment: @Aleks-DanielJakimenko thx, I didn't notice he has actually two expected output in question. I added that part.

Comment: for some reason your 2nd example leaves spaces in 3rd and 4th variables, e.g: `gawk -F'";"' -v OFS='";"' '{n=split($3,a,/,\s*/);for(i=1;i<=n;i++){$3=a[i];sub(/\s*to\s*/,"\";\"",$3);sub(/\s*from\s*/,"",$3);print}}' |head -2`
"390";"901";" 6000000 ";" 6009999";"ОАО \"Ростелеком\" (ОАО \"Сибирьтелеком\")";"Республика Хакасия";"13.05.09"
"";"954";" 1010000 ";" 1019999";"ЗАО \"Джи Ти Эн Ти\"";"Российская Федерация";"04.06.12"

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{ FS=OFS="\";\"" }
{
    gsub(/from /,"",$3)
    split($3,a,/ *, */)
    for (i=1;i in a;i++) {
        $3 = a[i]
        sub(/ to /,OFS,$3)
        print
    }
}
$
$ awk -f tst.awk file
"390";"902";"4670000";"4679999";"something1";"something2";"20.09.04"
"390";"902";"4680000";"4689999";"something1";"something2";"20.09.04"
"390";"902";"9960000";"9969999";"something1";"something2";"20.09.04"
"390";"903";"0770000";"0779999";"something3";"something4";"09.09.04"
"390";"903";"9170000";"9179999";"something3";"something4";"09.09.04"
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/, /","/g;s/^(([^;]*;){2})([^,]*),([^;]*)(.*)/\1\3\5\n\1\4\5/;P;D' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

filename='file.txt'
temp=$(mktemp)

sed 's/, */";"/g' "$filename" > "$temp" # replace commas with ;

echo -n > "$filename" # clear our file
while read line; do
    IFS=';' read -a fields <<< "$line" # make an array out of the string

    for ((i=2; i<${#fields[@]}-3; i++)); do
        from=$(echo "${fields[$i]}" | cut -d ' ' -f2)
        to=$(echo "${fields[$i]}" | cut -d ' ' -f4)
        echo "${fields[0]};${fields[1]};\"$from\";\"$to;${fields[-3]};${fields[-2]};${fields[-1]}" >> "$filename"
    done
done < "$temp"

rm "$temp"

exit 0
```

It is going to handle spaces before commas as well.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not what I need. Please look more into the example I gave, I need to split the line via 3rd field and also copy rest of the line. I've already coded something in PHP, because I'm not that good in sed/awk, I'll post the solution here once I got it.

Comment: omg, all of those subprocesses you're creating to parse one line of text!? +1 for chutzpah in using shell and `$()` and `((...))` constructs, but learn about ${var/s/r}, ${var%x}, ${var%%x}, ${var#y}, ${var##y} (they probably have limited applicability on this question, and you may know about them already). Sadly, -1 for subprocesses, so . . . . a wash.  Repent, repent and learn awk (or python or perl) ;-) Good  luck to all.

Comment: @shellter of course there are better ways using awk, but they're less readable as well. Just wanted to give an alternative that some people might like.

Comment: @Aleks-DanielJakimenko I'm more of a fan of Bash than Awk but this time I don't think Bash could be simpler than Awk, and even more readable. Also, I think it's a waste to use cut and command substitution. You could have just used special parameter expansion methods like ${X##Y}, etc.

Comment: @konsolebox I know about parameter expansion, but I fail to see how this is going to help in this case, could you explain?

Comment: @Aleks-DanielJakimenko I added another answer based on Bash for your reference.

Comment: Would fail if `something*` contained commas or semi-colons or backslashes or .... A shell is for sequencing calls to tools, not for parsing text files - that's what awk was invented to do and is very good at it.

Answer (score 1):

This is another way to do it in Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob

IFS=';'

while read -a FIELDS; do
    TEMP=${FIELDS[2]//\"}
    read -a RANGES <<< "${TEMP//,?( )/;}"
    for A in "${RANGES[@]}"; do
        echo "${FIELDS[0]};${FIELDS[1]};\"$A\";${FIELDS[*]:3}"
    done
done
```

Run with

```
bash script.sh < file
```

That would give the first intended output.

Or

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob

IFS=';'

while read -a FIELDS; do
    TEMP=${FIELDS[2]//@(\"|from )}
    read -a RANGES <<< "${TEMP//@(,?( )| to )/;}"
    for (( I = 0; I < ${#RANGES[@]}; I += 2 )); do
        echo "${FIELDS[0]};${FIELDS[1]};\"${RANGES[I]}\";\"${RANGES[I + 1]}\";${FIELDS[*]:3}"
    done
done
```

Which would get the second intended output.

Comment: That would fail if the text represented by `something1`, for example, contained a semi-colon. Separating the fields with the 3-char string `";"` as shown in the sample input would be more robust.

Comment: @EdMorton Ok I made an update for the possibility. The solution does not necessarily need to be like your suggestion as Bash also has strengths over Awk even with text parsing or manipulation of strings.

Comment: Interesting, that's not the solution I expected, I thought it'd be `sed 's/";"/<some char>/g' | script | sed 's/<some char>/";"/g'`. I actually can't see what that solution is doing!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using [python](/questions/tagged/python). I know you didn't tag it, but seems easier for me to handle `csv` files with a good parser. It splits third field (`row[2]`) with commas, later it splits each string of that field in spaces and extract the odd ones (`v.split()[1::2]`).

Content of `script.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import csv
import sys
import copy

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
        csvfile = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
        csvout = csv.writer(sys.stdout, delimiter=';', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        for row in csvfile:
                v3 = row[2].split(r', ')
                for v in v3:
                        newrow = copy.deepcopy(row)
                        fields = v.split()[1::2]
                        newrow[2:3] = fields
                        csvout.writerow(newrow)
```

Run it like:

```
python3 script.py infile
```

That yields:

```
"390";"902";"4670000";"4679999";"something1";"something2";"20.09.04"
"390";"902";"4680000";"4689999";"something1";"something2";"20.09.04"
"390";"902";"9960000";"9969999";"something1";"something2";"20.09.04"
"390";"903";"0770000";"0779999";"something3";"something4";"09.09.04"
"390";"903";"9170000";"9179999";"something3";"something4";"09.09.04"
```